# Implementing login for specific users in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, instagram-api

I'm creating an app and currently working on the login/sign-up. I found this tutorial (http://www.appcoda.com/login-signup-parse-swift/) but I was wondering if there were a way to accept only certain email addresses? Some pseudocode would be

//Confirm email address if it includes "@collge.KSU.edu"
//saves user info

Answer (score 1):

Well you kind of just answered your question but I guess something like:

```
Get username from user (or email or whatever)

if(username is valid) {
    move to different screen or show notification
}
else {
    display pop-up instructing the user their input is not valid
}
```

The main part is just parsing the String and making sure it is valid which I believe switch is already equip with. So for the case of a specific email, you could try `value.contains("@collge.KSU.edu")`, of course you'll have to be a bit more careful with using that to make sure they put it in the right spot.

Comment: Thanks Sacent, Using Swift I want to try something like this                                                             if emailString.rangeOfString("@collge.KSU.edu") == nil {
        print("Must be KSU email.")
}

Comment: A careful thing to note is that someone could possibly enter the following as an input and it be valid: `@collge.KSU.edu@gmail.com` - at least I believe that is possible, I can't check using Swift at the moment.